# how to increment a global char inside a for loop? django

Tags: python, django, for-loop, char, increment

I am doing this in a view not in django template though

I want to try incrementing a char with numbers in a for loop but somehow I keep on getting the same char.

let's say I want `A0, A1, A2 up to A9 then B0, B1 up to B9`

Cans someone give me a hand?

I have something like this but it keeps on giving me `B` though

```
    start_char = 'A'
    for x in range(15):
        ending_number = str(x)[-1]
        print(chr(ord(start_char) + 1) + ending_number)
```

Comment: Try `print(chr(ord(start_char) + x))`

Comment: @bulbus my bad with explanation, let me edit my post.

Comment: `print(chr(ord(start_char) + x/10) + str(x%10))`

Comment: @bulbus ah! so what you just did is `x/10` which the first `0-9` would actually give 0 which then means no increment then `10-19` would be one increment and so on then `x%10` gets the last of the number right/

Comment: That's right! Yes, `1/10=9/10...=0` , `10/10,11/10...=1` ;; `1%10=11%10=1`,`2%10=12%10=2`...

Comment: @bulbus do you want post it do I can click it as answer?

Comment: Using global variables is always a bad idea. Using global variables in a multiprocess, multiuser environment like Django is a terrible idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print(chr(ord(start_char) + x/10) + str(x%10))`
Explanation below...
For increments in the first character, use div by int
 `1/10 = 9/10...=0`
`10/10=11/10...=1`
For the trailing number, use remainder operator
 `1%10=11%10=1`
`2%10=12%10=2`...